# BufferReader inside try clause : cannot find symbol

Tags: java, try-catch, java-io

I'm trying to write a class that handles reading files. In order to read the file word by word, I used the following code which I found on the internet. Netbeans seems to disagree and says that it cannot find the symbole br inside the while loop.

```
public class Reader {
  public String file2string() {
    String line;
    try (InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("smth")) {
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Reader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    {
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] words = line.split(" ");
        // Now you have a String array containing each word in the current line
      }
    }
    return line;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly if you are asking people to try and read it.

Comment: your `while loop` is outside the `try-catch` so the variable `br` is out of the scope yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is out the `try` so the variable `br` is unknown in the context. Put your `while-loop` inside the `try` structure like here:

```
public String file2string() {
    String line = null;
    try (InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("smth")) {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            // Now you have a String array containing each word in the current line
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }  
    return line;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `{}` block after your try statement

```
{
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
}
```

And then you have another `{}` block.

```
{
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] words = line.split(" ");
        // Now you have a String array containing each word in the current line
    }
}
```

Variables declared in the first block are not visible in the second block.

Combine the two blocks:

```
public String file2string() {
    String line;
    try (InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("smth")) {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] words = line.split(" ");           
        }
        return line;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    // you need to decide what you want to return here if you got an exception.
}
```

You seem to be splitting each line and ignoring the result, and then returning the last line of the file. I don't know why you're doing that, or what you were actually trying to do; but this is how to fix the compile error.

Comment: How do i resolve the problem ? i can't declare the buffeedreader before declarinf the inputstreamreader

Comment: Basically, put the code that uses `br` >>inside<< the `try` block.

Answer (score 1):

The variable "br" is declared in the try{} block, so that's its scope. It won't be visible outside of that block. Try putting the while loop inside the try block.